# Facebook UI dialog callback not fired

Tags: trigger.io

I am using forge.facebook.ui to send app requests to users. The dialogue opens as expected and selects the correct user to send the invite to. However it appears the callbacks (success or error) are never fired when the user clicks 'send'. Code example below:

```
forge.facebook.ui(
    {
      title: 'Invite your Friend,
      method: 'apprequests',
      to: 1234567,
      message: 'Sign up'
    },
    function(response) {
      forge.logging.info(response); // Never Called
    },
    function (e) {
      forge.logging.info('facebook failed: ' + JSON.stringify(e)); // Never Called
    }
  );
```

In the past this was working correctly.

Comment: Sounds like you've found a bug, could you let me know what version of Android or iOS you're seeing this on so we can recreate it and track down what's going on?

Comment: I'm seeing this issue on IOS6 on an iPhone 5 and the simulator. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This did turn out to be a bug introduced in a recent Forge version, I've just committed a fix which will be in the next Forge platform version, which we should be deploying tomorrow (06/11/2012).

Comment: Great. Thanks for your help Connorhd.